# Proof leaking in Coq extraction?

Tags: coq

In order to understand how general recursive `Function` definitions works, and how they comply with Coq's structural recursion constraint, I tried to reimplement it on the Peano natural numbers. I want to define recursive `nat -> nat` functions that can use any previous values, not just the predecessor. Here is what I did :

```
  Definition nat_strong_induction_set
             (* erased at extraction, type specification *)
             (P : nat -> Set)
             (* The strong induction step. To build the P n it can, but does not have to, 
                recursively query the construction of any previous P k's. *)
             (ind_step : forall n : nat, (forall k : nat, (lt k n -> P k)) -> P n)
             (n : nat)
    : P n.
  Proof.
    (* Force the hypothesis of ind_step as a standard induction hypothesis *)
    assert (forall m k : nat, lt k m -> P k) as partial_build.
    { induction m.
      - intros k H0. destruct k; inversion H0.
      - intros k H0. apply ind_step. intros k0 H1. apply IHm. apply (lt_transitive k0 k).
        assumption. apply le_lt_equiv. assumption. }
    apply (partial_build (S n) n). apply succ_lt.
  Defined.
```

I used some custom lemmas on nats that I didn't paste here. It works, I managed to define the euclidean division `div a b` with it, which recursively uses `div (a-b) b`. The extraction is almost what I expected :

```
let nat_strong_induction_set ind_step n =
  let m = S n in
  let rec f n0 k =
    match n0 with
    | O -> assert false (* absurd case *)
    | S n1 -> ind_step k (fun k0 _ -> f n1 k0)
  in f m n
```

Except for the `n0` parameter. We see that the only effect of this parameter is to stop the recursion at the `S n`-nth step. The extraction also mentions that this `assert false` should not happen. So why is it extracted ? This seems better

```
let nat_strong_induction_set ind_step n =
  let rec f k = ind_step k (fun k0 _ -> f k0)
  in f n
```

It looks like a glitch of Coq's structural recursion constraint, to ensure the termination of all recursions. The Coq definition of `nat_strong_induction_set` writes `lt k n`, so Coq knows only previous `P k`'s will be queried. This makes a decreasing chain in the nats, which is forced to terminate in less than `S n` steps. This allows a structural recursive definition on an additional fuel parameter `n0` starting at `S n`, it won't affect the result. So if it is only a part of the termination proof, why is it not erased by the extraction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your match is not erased because your definition mixes two things: the termination argument, where the match is needed, and the computationally relevant recursive call, where it isn't.

To force erasure, you need to convince Coq that the match is computationally irrelevant.  You can do so by making the termination argument -- that is, the induction on `m` -- produce the proof of a proposition instead of a function of type `forall m k, lt k m -> P k`.  Luckily, the standard library provides an easy way of doing so, with the `Fix` combinator:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Wf_nat.

Definition nat_strong_induction_set
             (P : nat -> Set)
             (ind_step : forall n : nat, (forall k : nat, (lt k n -> P k)) -> P n)
             (n : nat)
    : P n :=
  Fix lt_wf P ind_step n.
```

Here, `lt_wf` is a proof that `lt` is well-founded.  When you extract this function, you get

```
let rec nat_strong_induction_set ind_step n =
  ind_step n (fun y _ -> nat_strong_induction_set ind_step y)
```

which is exactly what you wanted.

(As an aside, note that you don't need well-founded recursion to define division -- check for instance how it is defined in the [Mathematical Components library](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/doc/mathcomp-1.5/MathComp.div.html).)

Comment: The library's definition of well-founded relations is superb. So simple... yet I'd failed to code it myself for 3 days. That gives me another question about inductive properties I'll post.

Comment: I don't understand how the definition of division in the Mathematical Components library is structural recursive. It is the same algorithm, which iteratively subtracts the denominator from the numerator. Is there some SSReflect black magic involved ?

Comment: @V.Semeria Coq's termination checker is more clever than you might think. It is able to detect that if `m - n = S m'`, then `m'` is a subterm of `m`, because the definition of subtraction (https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/8.4pl3/stdlib/Coq.Init.Peano.html#minus) returns its first argument, not 0, on the base case! (Admittedly, this is kind of a hack, but it does come in handy in this case.)